# Solr Multiple Language Search

Tags: .net, solr, sitecore

I want to know how should i configure Solr for multilinguial search . I have a website having Solr search. This is working for English i want to work it for all languages.

Below is my Schema ..

```
<field name="url" type="string" indexed="true" stored="true" required="true" multiValued="false" />
        <field name="title" type="text" indexed="true" stored="true" required="false" multiValued="false" />
        <field name="content" type="text" indexed="true" stored="true" required="true" multiValued="false" />
        <field name="contenttype" type="string" indexed="true" stored="true" required="false" multiValued="false" />
        <field name="contentsize" type="integer" indexed="false" stored="true" required="false" multiValued="false" />
        <field name="timestamp" type="date" indexed="true" stored="true" required="false" multiValued="false" />
        <field name="language" type="string" indexed="true" stored="true" required="false" multiValued="false" />
        <field name="description" type="text" indexed="true" stored="true" required="false" multiValued="false" />
        <field name="keywords" type="text" indexed="true" stored="true" required="false" multiValued="false" />    
    <field name="keywordsNoneStemmed" type="string" indexed="true" stored="true" required="false" multiValued="true" />    
        <field name="thumbnail" type="string" indexed="true" stored="true" required="false" multiValued="false" />
    <field name="virtualitem" type="boolean" indexed="true" stored="true" required="false" multiValued="false" />
    <field name="section" type="string" indexed="true" stored="true" required="false" multiValued="false"></field>
    </fields>
```

When i saw the log file Solr is indexing URL in different languages but i don't know how to show search result .. My website is using .net technologies

Answer (score 0):

There is no magic bullet. If you know the language of input texts, then you could store languages in different fields and use different stemmers depending on language. Or you could avoid the stemmers and instead use ngrams.

If you continue to use stopwords and protected words then you will need to edit those so that they are not too agressive. For instance "is" and "by" are stopwords in English but they mean "ice" and "town" in many Scandinavian languages. Therefore you would remove them from stopwords but you might want to add "je" and "il" because they are French stopwords. But "je" has different meanings in languages like Dutch and Serbian so maybe not...

Start by trimming down the chain of tokenizers, analysers, filters, and then do some testing with people who are fluent in other languages. Get them to show you weird results and explain why they are weird. And look at Oriental languages because ngrams are really the only way to deal with them.